# remove featured image from gallery woocommerce

Tags: gallery, plugins

I am using wooCommerce. When i set the featured image for a woocommerce product, it shows up as the first/main image in the gallery on the product details page. I need to remove the featured image from the gallery only. How to do this?

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include the relevant code, in context, that is used to output the gallery on the product page.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922849/woocommerce-hide-featured-image-on-product-detail-page

Haven't tested it, but it might work out for you.

Comment: I think the example will remove the featured image from the product detail page too. I just wanted to remove it from the gallery under the featured image only.

Comment: Hmm, this person was trying to do what you are: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278291/remove-featured-image-from-showing-on-product-display-page-wordpresswoocommerce

Comment: Whats the gallery? Is it a template or page included in or generated by WooCommerce? Or is it something you added? There's at least 8 templates for products included.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove both and then add the thumbnail images back.

Paste this code at the end of your child themes functions file.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 20 );
```

You would also want to change the size of the thumbnail images

Sources:

http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails.html

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/